# Adding weights to dataftrame after ebalance

Tags: r, matching, weighting

I am trying to add weights produced with the entropy balancing reweighting ebal package to a dataframe in order to use them thereafter in regression analysis with balanced samples.
The code that that I used for weighting is:

```
# install.packages("ebal")
library(ebal)
out.eb<- ebalance(Treatment=Treatment,X=X,constraint.tolerance = 2)
```

To then add the weights to the dataframe I assumed that treatment units are weighted as 1, and that control units should get the weights that were produced with ebal, so:

```
data$weights <- ifelse(Treatment==1,1,out.eb$w)
```

I think that I got it wrong, but am not sure what would be the right solution.
Would be grateful for your advice.

Comment: Why do you think that you got it wrong?

Comment: because when i compare the covariate means of treated and non-treated units in the dataset they differ, and the difference is actually larger than in the original dataset

Comment: Hello! Could you (1) add a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and (2) specify the package(s) needed to use the function? I believe that here, it is ebal, so I added it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the following:

```
data$weights <- 1
data$weights[Treatment == 1] <- eb$w
```

This has to do with how `ifelse()` is structured. The number of elements in each of the arguments to `ifelse()` should be of length 1 or have the same length at he first argument. Because `ebal()` only produces weights for the treated units, `eb$w` has fewer elements than `Treatment`, so the assignment fails. Using the syntax above avoids this problem.

Another option to look at is the `WeightIt` package, which also implements entropy balancing and may be easier to use.